# VB 2019 project settings empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I want to store startup settings for my project. When I go to the project Properties/Settings, it's empty except for a link that says, "This project does not have a default settings file. Click here to create one." When I click the link to add one, it says "The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002." So, how do I add a default settings file?

Comment: What kind of project have you created?

Comment: You must be targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework. Did you mean to do that? If you create a VB WinForms app project, you can choose ".NET", which is .NET Core and targets .NET 5.0 by default, or you can choose ".NET Framework", which will target up to .NET Framework 4.8. .NET Framework doesn't require you to create a settings file. In a .NET Core project, I see the same behaviour as you. It appears to be a bug in VS, which is not too surprising, given how new VB WinForms support in .NET Core is. I will try a VS repair. I suggest that you do the same.

Comment: I repaired VS and I see the same behaviour. This appears to be a bug and you should report it to Microsoft. In the meantime, you will have to create a .NET Framework project if you want to use application settings. Note that, while you cannot convert a .NET Framework project to a .NET Core project later, when the issue is fixed, you can add project items, e.g. forms, from one to the other. While I haven't tested it, another option may be to add a settings file to a C# project, which works for me, and then try making the corresponding changes to a VB project manually.

Comment: What's the type of your application? You can add some pictures to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments, this seems to be a bug in VS and ought to be reported to Microsoft. As a temporary workaround, you can actually copy the settings files from a .NET Framework project into a .NET Core project. As far as I can tell from examining various VB and C# projects targeting .NET Framework and .NET Core, the settings files are the same in each case, so there's no issue copying between them. Here's what I did:

1. Added a VB WinForms app project targeting .NET Framework to the same solution.
2. Clicked the *Show All Files* button in the Solution Explorer for both projects.
3. Expanded the *My Project* node for both projects.
4. Dragged the *Settings.settings* item from the .NET Framework project to the .NET Core project.

It seemed to work as expected after that.

Comment: Thank you jmcilhinney. I don't do a lot of programming, so I was not aware of .NET Core. From what I can tell, I don't need .NET Core. So, I switched my project to .NET Framework. But, I think I will try playing around with .NET Core later, following your steps.